# grails <gui:tab. Passing model

Tags: grails

I am using the grails ui component tabView. For each tab I am invoking an action (which of course is backed by a view). How can I pass some parameters to that action ? 
As I know the `<gui:tab` tag doesn't accept any model/params parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it have to do with gui:tab? Just put an [g:include](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html) inside the tab:

```
<gui:tab label="title">
  <g:include action="a" params="[p: $p]" />
</gui:tab>
```

Or is it about something else?

Answer (score 0):

In grails version 2.0, I used:

```
<gui:tab label="Loaded from Controller">
  <g:include controller="myController" action="edit" id="${dataInstance.id}" abc="2" />
</gui:tab>
```

Because I experienced problems if I used `params`.